# Is there a way to disable JxBrowser content scaling?

Tags: jxbrowser

**Background**: I'm running JDK 1.8 on my native Java Swing app, and have JxBrowser 7.2 for my web app. I can't upgrade my JDK version because of other issues.

I read [content-scaling](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013079-content-scaling) is automatically applied. I wonder if there is a way to turn off this content-scaling since other components of my app does not support scaling based on environments' HiDPI display, and fonts look bad when user has scaled their system display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try configuring the engine with the `--force-device-scale-factor=1` switch as show below:

```
Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(
    EngineOptions.newBuilder(rendering_mode)
            .addSwitch("--force-device-scale-factor=1")
            .build());
```

This option forces Chromium to use a fixed scale factor and doesn't read it dynamically according to the current location on screen.